# Understanding binding in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've come across this piece of code in OpenGL:

```
glGenVertexArrays(GLsizei n, GLuint *arrays);
glBindVertexArray(GLuint array);
```

The first line as stated in the doc: *returns n vertex array object names in arrays* and the second line: *binds the vertex array object with name array.*

I can only guess that here *bind* and *return in* mean different but, these functions sound as if they're doing the same thing.  What is it that this term **bind** refer to and what function does it do different from `glGenVertexArrays()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glGenVertexArrays()` is akin to `malloc()` or `new` in that it allocates resources (here, the IDs for Vertex Array Objects or VAOs) that you can use later.

`glBindVertexArray()` controls which VAO is active -- part of the OpenGL global state. It takes a VAO ID that was allocated by `glGenVertexArrays()`, creates an underlying OpenGL object for it (if needed), and makes it the current one so that other OpenGL operations apply to it. (It can also de-activate the current VAO.)

More details can be found [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1377833&seqNum=8).

Comment: active? can there be multiple active arrays or just one at a time then?

Comment: and what is the size of the allocation? or is the allocation space specified ...?

Comment: [`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) doesn't allocate anything. It just reserves name id's, which can be used for vertex array objects. [`glBindVertexArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexArray.xhtml) creates a single VAO object with the given name (if if doesn't exist yet) and makes it current. The sentence *"a VAO that was created by glGenVertexArrays()"* is nonsense.

Comment: @Rabbid76: Clarified.

Comment: @metal The point is, that `glGenVertexArrays` just reserves names it doesn't reserve any memory. `glBindVertexArray` actually creates an object on the GPU (when it is called the 1st time for a name id) and makes it current. The current VAO is a global state.

Comment: Right. I think I say approximately that in my revised answer. Perhaps the word "allocates" is causing confusion, but it is functionally equivalent to "reserves" here -- both meaning *sets aside* or *assigns*.

Comment: @Rabbid76: While that is technically true, it's also generally useless, since outside of DSA you can't do anything with most objects until you bind them.

Answer (score 2):

`glGenVertexArrays()` : generated `n` handles for Vertex Array. handle values are returned `arrays`

`glBindVertexArray()` : set a `VertexArray` active. From now on, you can call  opengl API utilizing the `vertexArray`.

There is many similar API in OpenGL..
`bindXXX` means make it active.